# How to fix error when install elasticsearch7.7.0 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

I am trying to install Elasticsearch on windows 10. I got zip file in https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-7-6-0.

And I run command in terminal as following:
[image]
I need your help.
Thanks.

Comment: which java version are you using?

Comment: java version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22

Comment: It has been deprecated since Java 17, try using Java 16 by downloading and setting JAVA_HOME variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must install Java 16 for Elasticsearch-7.6.0.
https://www.techspot.com/downloads/7407-java-se-16.html.

And Then download elasticsearch7.6.0 https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-7-6-0.
Run Command in source directory.

```
.\bin\elasticsearch.bat
```